# Android: BluetoothSocket.connect() blocks wifi connection

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I couldn't find solution for this one:

As said in official [Android documentation about Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), after devices are paired, they are stored into set that can be obtain by [`BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices())... I wanted to create logic that connect to some device if it is paired and accessible. (I'm searching whether device is present in bondedDevices and want to pair)

The only way I can tell the device is paired is by calling [`BluetoothSocket.connect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect()) and wait whether I was able to connect to device or not. Correct me if I'm not right. And I'm retrying it until device is connected...

But... [`BluetoothSocket.connect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect()) is somehow blocking wifi communication (wifi icon is displayed for some time in status bar but not working). So other apps like Chrome cannot browse over internet.

**Questions**:

- Is there any way to get list of accessible devices so I will not have to try connecting to bluetooth socket?
- If not, is there any workaround so that wifi will not turn off?
- If not, I believe I have to try it once and if not possible then require user input so that I will block wifi for shorter time, right?

Thanks